# Multiple DataContext in a View vs MVVM? Is that right?

Tags: c#, wpf, datacontext

I have the following problem: I'm building a chat WPF application on which I want the user to be connected with different accounts to GTalk. I've made a ViewModel that permits handling the communication but I don't know which is the best way to handle DataContext. I think that I need different DataContexts for every connection instance but I don't know if this is the right way and don't know how to define multiple DataContexts in a View.

Answer (score 1):

A `DataContext` provides the default binding source for an element in the view. It is inherited from parent to child within the visual tree. You can change the `DataContext` for any element by binding it to some property of its parent `DataContext`. This is a common way of creating 'islands' that bind to a child view model.

For example, if you have a User view model that has an `Address` Property, you can render this in an `AddressUserControl` as follows:

```
<StackPanel>
   ... elements bound to properties of User ...

   <AddressUserControl DataContext="{Binding Address}"/>
</StackPanel>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a variable number of accounts, you can use the ItemsControl.

The rough idea behind this: You can bind the ItemsControl to a list of "Sub-ViewModels" in your main ViewModel and define a DataTemplate (= a View) for each of them. The DataContext of each DataTemplate is automatically assigned to a corresponding item in your ViewModel's list.